# Action if app has received push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Afternoon, perhaps you can help me.

When my app loads ... or comes back from the background ... is it possible to tell whether it has received a push notification in the recent past? Or indeed was loaded as a result of a push alert?

I ask for the simple reason that I would like to have my app load in a different way if it has.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It is midnight here dude :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only information you can get from a push notification is when it's opened from a push notification. There is no way to get information from other push notifications that have been received but were not opened.

Comment: Ah ok ... time to think of another way. Thanks

Comment: You might be able to do this in iOS 7 with the new background processing. Can't say more about this since it's still under NDA.

Comment: But that is info I could presumably get hold of as I have a dev account?

Comment: Yes. Just go through the videos and guides of the new API's